# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 using C libraries

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos

I have been having a lot of linker errors. I made sure to install all of the libraries I need via macports. I sorted out all of the include errors, but now I have a lot of linker errors left.

HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = /opt/local/include /usr/include /opt/local/include/json
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = /opt/local/lib /usr/local/lib

```
Build target PianoLounge

Ld /Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Products/Debug/PianoLounge.app/Contents/MacOS/PianoLounge normal x86_64
    cd /Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Products/Debug -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -F/Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PianoLounge.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Cocoa -o /Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Products/Debug/PianoLounge.app/Contents/MacOS/PianoLounge

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gcry_cipher_close", referenced from:
      _PianoDestroyPartner in piano.o
  "_gcry_cipher_decrypt", referenced from:
      _PianoDecryptString in crypt.o
  "_gcry_cipher_encrypt", referenced from:
      _PianoEncryptString in crypt.o
  "_gcry_cipher_open", referenced from:
      _PianoInit in piano.o
  "_gcry_cipher_setkey", referenced from:
      _PianoInit in piano.o
  "_gnutls_bye", referenced from:
      _WaitressFetchCall in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_certificate_allocate_credentials", referenced from:
      _WaitressFetchCall in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_certificate_free_credentials", referenced from:
      _WaitressFetchCall in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_certificate_get_peers", referenced from:
      _WaitressTlsVerify in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_certificate_type_get", referenced from:
      _WaitressTlsVerify in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_credentials_set", referenced from:
      _WaitressFetchCall in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_deinit", referenced from:
      _WaitressFetchCall in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_handshake", referenced from:
      _WaitressConnect in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_init", referenced from:
      _WaitressFetchCall in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_record_recv", referenced from:
      _WaitressGnutlsRead in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_record_send", referenced from:
      _WaitressGnutlsWrite in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_set_default_priority", referenced from:
      _WaitressFetchCall in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_transport_set_ptr", referenced from:
      _WaitressFetchCall in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_transport_set_pull_function", referenced from:
      _WaitressFetchCall in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_transport_set_push_function", referenced from:
      _WaitressFetchCall in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_x509_crt_deinit", referenced from:
      _WaitressTlsVerify in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_x509_crt_get_fingerprint", referenced from:
      _WaitressTlsVerify in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_x509_crt_import", referenced from:
      _WaitressTlsVerify in waitress.o
  "_gnutls_x509_crt_init", referenced from:
      _WaitressTlsVerify in waitress.o
  "_json_object_array_add", referenced from:
      _PianoRequest in request.o
  "_json_object_array_get_idx", referenced from:
      _PianoResponse in response.o
  "_json_object_array_length", referenced from:
      _PianoResponse in response.o
  "_json_object_get_boolean", referenced from:
      _PianoResponse in response.o
      _PianoJsonParseStation in response.o
  "_json_object_get_double", referenced from:
      _PianoResponse in response.o
  "_json_object_get_int", referenced from:
      _PianoResponse in response.o
  "_json_object_get_object", referenced from:
      _PianoResponse in response.o
  "_json_object_get_string", referenced from:
      _PianoResponse in response.o
      _PianoJsonStrdup in response.o
  "_json_object_new_array", referenced from:
      _PianoRequest in request.o
  "_json_object_new_boolean", referenced from:
      _PianoRequest in request.o
  "_json_object_new_int", referenced from:
      _PianoRequest in request.o
  "_json_object_new_object", referenced from:
      _PianoRequest in request.o
  "_json_object_new_string", referenced from:
      _PianoRequest in request.o
  "_json_object_object_add", referenced from:
      _PianoRequest in request.o
  "_json_object_object_get", referenced from:
      _PianoResponse in response.o
      _PianoJsonStrdup in response.o
      _PianoJsonParseStation in response.o
  "_json_object_put", referenced from:
      _PianoRequest in request.o
      _PianoResponse in response.o
  "_json_object_to_json_string", referenced from:
      _PianoRequest in request.o
  "_json_tokener_parse", referenced from:
      _PianoResponse in response.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the required libraries gnutls, gcrypt and json to link against. Unless you tell Xcode what libraries to link against it won't have any idea. It will look something like this:

```
-lgnutls -lgcrypt -ljson
```

(That is an example, I am not sure what libraries specifically are required).

You'll want to add those as extra libraries to link against in your Xcode project.